# Como comentar código HTML con ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Este código en Reactjs es transpilado por babeljs, quiero saber si se puede comentar el código HTML  en esta función.

```
var SearchBar = React.createClass({
    render : function () {
        return (
            <form>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Search...' className='form-control'/>
                <p>
                    <input type='checkbox' className='form-control'/>
                    {' '}
                    Only show products in stock
                </p>                
            </form>
        )
    }
})
```

Nota :  No funciona el /*  */  -  //

Comment: Debido a que React pasa por un proceso de transpilación de JSX a JS y HTML, los comentarios en HTML son completamente ignorados, y debido al poder de la sintaxis, usted no puede dejar comentarios en él.

Answer (score 4):

Para comentar código en `React JSX` , una línea simplemente usa: `//`

```
var a = React.DOM.p(null,
        "Mi primer línea",
//      "Segunda linea comentada"
        "tercer línea"
);
```

o un bloque completo entre los contenedores `{/*` y `*/}`:

```
 return (
  <div>
      {/* <form>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Search...' className='form-control'/>
            <p>
      </p>                
        </form>*/}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: con react no funciona asi

Comment: agrega los brackets: {/* y */} recuerda que los brackets son necesarios cuando estas dentro de un tag html como en el ejemplo que te muestro.

Comment: eso funciona para comentar javascript, pero no HTML

Comment: En la doc oficial (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#comments) nos sugiere la manera en la cual @Elenasys describe. Si no te esta funcionando debe ser por algo más.

Answer (score 3):

Haz esto:

```
{/* Esto es un comentario */}
```

Aquí está un ejemplo en [codepen](http://codepen.io/bradleyboy/pen/OPBpGw)

Con información de [este sitio](http://wesbos.com/react-jsx-comments/)

Comment: con react no funciona asi

Comment: Daniel, no funciona dentro del código de tu método?

Comment: asi es @Elenasys

Comment: @DanielHernández así se comenta, te dejé un ejemplo, trata de comentar como te hemos dicho y verás  que sí :)

Comment: quiero comentar el HTML , no el javascript

Comment: ¿Lo intentaste con el ejemplo? Yo comente el HTML dentro de JavaScript sin problemas. Pero bueno, suerte.

Comment: Si lo que buscas es <!-- un comentario --> eso no se puede lo que te sugiere @x4mp73r es la forma correcta {/* <div>texto comentado</div> */}

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de la sección donde quieras comentar, si quieres comentar en el render tiene que utilizar: `{/* Aquí lo que quieres comentar */ }.` 
Si quieres comentar una linea en una función simplemente utilizar las formas conocidas `//Para una sola linea`
 o

```
/* Para varias lineas*/
```

Espero te sirva mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {/* <form>
 <input type='text' placeholder='Search...' className='form-control'/>
<p>
<input type='checkbox' className='form-control'/>
{' '}
Only show products in stock
                </p>                
</form>*/}
```

puedes usar esto con el atajo de control + } (en window es)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).